# how to connect mysql workbench to hostinger database

Tags: mysql, database-connection, hosting, mysql-workbench

I am working on database project, my database is on [hostinger](https://www.hostinger.in/). I want to connect mysql workbench to hostinger.

can please someone guide me how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to your hpanel
2. Select your website hosting click **Manage**
3. Go to Bottom page Under Database's click **Remote MySQL**
4. Check Any Host and Select your Database cick **Create**
5. Copy the hostname(which is something like sqlxxx.main-hosting.xx or IP 19x.xxx.xx.xx) located on top of IPv type Field

Goto workbench:

1. Create New Connection
2. Connection Method **Standard(TCP/IP)**
3. Under Parameters tab Hostname Field Enter Copied **Hostname(sqlxxx.main-hosting.xx or IP 19x.xxx.xx.xx)**
4. Port Field Enter:**3306**
5. Enter the Username & Password credentials when you created your database in Hostinger

Comment: Yes this is working fine... Just keep in mind to put _full username_ while connecting. for eg.  **u623454863_amarkumar**

Comment: It took me finding this 2 year old stack overflow answer to figure out why I couldn't connect to my Hostinger database. Did not realize the uXXXXXX needed to be at the front of the username.

Answer (score 3):

In cpanel:

1. Add remote IP Address to Remote MySQL

In Operating System: ODBC and MySQL Workbench

1. Close MySQL Workbench
2. Download and Install 32-bit or 64-bit MySQL ODBC connector from MySQL website
3. Restart PC
4. Configure ODBC (Windows run Win+R: %windir%\System32\odbcad32.exe )
5. Add source and choose: MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver
6. Choose Data Source Name
7. TCP/IP Server: mysql.hostinger.[top-level domain] (e.g. mysql.hostinger.nl or mysql.hostinger.in)
   !!! or Public IP address if it's given in cpanel at Remote MySQL on top of the page.
8. Port: 3306
9. Fill in: User and Password
10. Test connection
11. Start MySQL Workbench
12. Fill in same data as ODBC connection and test connection.
13. First SQL command have to be: USE [database name] ;
14. show tables;

Comment: Hey, I also tried this... seems to connect and I can run USE [database]; but seem to get nothing after that... it almost immediately disconnects.  Any suggestions?

Comment: This is not working https://postimg.cc/6y46Vfcq check this error screenshot